Etiqueta codigo ZPL, rotar todo el texto
Tengo este código ZPL

que es una etiqueta de una honeywell, continua, de 10cm de ancho por 15cm de alto.
El problema es que la etiqueta sale con el texto invertido, necesitaria rotarlo 90° como para que salta bien derecho con la etiqueta de forma vertical, tal como se las dibujo en la segunda imagen 
Como puedo modificar mi codigo o que comando puedo poner para que rote el texto a como lo necesito?
Muchas gracias de antemano
saludos.
